# How would I explain this ER diagram (ignoring the hasMajor relationship)?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I'm very unsure about the unique attribute that belongs to the Class entity. Would I write (key attributes in bold):
Class(**classNo**, schedule, room)
or:
Class(deptCode, courseNo, etc)?
How would this effect what references what?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZMyp.png)

Comment: Neither:  class, schedule and room are the unique key to class entity. I say this because Class ID represents a unique combination of course, section and dept.  It wouldn't repeat for the same course, section and department.  yet classID could be assigned to multiple rooms and times.  As such it can't be the unique key of Class.  Thus the combination of ClassNo, Schedule, and Room is what makes a record unique in CLASS.  So first is close; but all objects are bold as it takes each value to make a unique key.  The same class could be held at the same time; but in different rooms for example.

Comment: When thinking though this it always helps to walk though specific examples:  So if ENG 101 for section 2 is a class record (ID 12324), would I have different class ID's for Eng 101 Sec 2 if it's held in different places or different times?  The content of the class is the same so "no" should be the your answer... Thus ID 12324 would repeat in the class entity; thus it's not unqiue.  But the combination of schedule, and room would make it unique. (Assuming schedule defines start/end reoccurrence.)  Leaving us with CLASS(**ClassNo, Schedule, Room**) <bolded>